# Installer Setup for Java (Eclipse) Project

Tags: java, windows, linux, installation

Currently I am working on a Java based project with MySQL database in the back end. I need to create a setup for my project. Which Installer would be appropriate?
I need to create a common installer setup for both **Windows and Linux platforms.**

**Additional :** I have tried InstallJammer but it is quite complex and the forums related are closed.

What installer would you suggest for my project?
Please avoid giving the tutorials for differnt installers as I have already referenced.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why can't you just package in a directory with all required Jars, and a shell script and a bat script files?

Comment: @Nishant Can you explain in a little more as I am a beginner to setup creation. I need the setup for our future projects also.

Comment: Does the client application have a GUI?  For those I would use [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) as the installer/updater for the app. and the installer of the DB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a folder structure like

```
app
 |
 |-- lib
 |    `- <jar files>
 |
 |-- bin
 |    |- app.jar
 |    |- app.sh
 |    `- app.bat
 |
 `-- README
```

your app.sh looks like

```
#you need to fix class path, a relative path will cause issue when running from a diff PWD
java -cp .:../lib/jar1.jar:../lib/jar2.jar -jar app.jar
```

your app.bat looks like

```
#you need to fix class path, a relative path will cause issue when running from a diff PWD
java -cp .;../lib/jar1.jar;../lib/jar2.jar -jar app.jar
```

To execute it, `cd bin`, based on your system run shell or bat script.

Comment: Actually i need to create a GUI setup for my application.

Comment: why do you need a complicated setup? Just zip the `app` dir, and send to your clients. They will unzip and use it. There is nothing like _installing_ here. It's more like complete packaging.